# I don't know why but my ajax POST method is not returning any response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my code , When I click on submit , somehow the data is inserting but that echo data in back php form is not showing in this front ajax js code , please tell me if anything is wrong in my data

```
var formData = new FormData(this);    
$.ajax({
    url: '../back/regback.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {  
        alert(data);
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
}
return false;
```

ok this is my full js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    $('form#off').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();   

        if($('#name').val()==''){
            $('#nameid').text('Plase Select Customer Name ');
            return false;
           }
        else{
            var formData = new FormData(this);    
            $.ajax({
                url: '../back/regback.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert('data has been added');
                error: (err)=>{console.warn(err)}
                    // location.href='gst_chargeoff.php';
                    alert(data);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure using '../back/' is ok, you may enter url path

Comment: Have a quick eyeball on the Network panel for errors

Comment: Can we have the HTML? We don't know what is "this" and I didn't get your question

Comment: Does this refer to a value? I don't see you doing a e.preventDefault() on the event too

Comment: Can you show us the complete JS code? For example, there's an extra `}` in the end of the code you've posted. Is it a typo or does it refer to something before the ajax call? You should also show us the PHP file (regback.php) that suppose to return the response.

Comment: <script>
    $("#sub").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        query = $.post({
            url : 'check_ajax.php',
            data : {'name': $('input[name=name]').val(), 'pw': $('#pw').val()},
        });
        query.done(function(response){
            $('#answer').html(response);
        });
    });
</script>  Try something like that. We don't know that much with what you posted otherwise

Comment: even.prevent default ok let me check , i did not use it yet

Comment: ok i used event.peventDefault but result is the same as i mentioned

Comment: Well, you won't prevent form from submitting in php if you don't use it

Comment: You have a call for AJAX. But No call for answer or when request is done to retrieve datas too

Comment: I suggest you take a closer look at how form submitting looks using jquery manual. Your code lacks a lot of elements

Comment: @Dice That depends on how you are you are calling the function.Return false can also prevent form submission.

Comment: @Satya As other have mentioned, you need to share more information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I'm not sur his return is placed correctly, and it's easier for beginner (I believe) to put that prevent default line on begining of ajax request. Plus there are typos

Comment: Please include the code from `../back/regback.php` and `../back/gstback.php`

Comment: You're missing a `}` before `else{`

Comment: You also just updated the URL + the first and the second code block doesn't match. Which one should we look at? Please check the dev console for errors. There's too many inconsistencies and unknowns here (even though we've asked to see _all_ code, including the PHP, several times). This is a rabbit hole I'm not gonna fall into. I'm out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call is working fine. It is also getting response from the url. If there would be any server side error , It can be detected in the error: of the ajax parameter.

In your code it was written incorrectly, the same i have corrected in the below code, you will get the error in console if there will be any server side error. else the response will be returned properly.

Check the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    $('form#off').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();   

        if($('#name').val()==''){
            $('#nameid').text('Plase Select Customer Name ');
            return false;
           }
        else{
            var formData = new FormData(this);    
            $.ajax({
                url: '../back/regback.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert('data has been added');
                    // location.href='gst_chargeoff.php';
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `error` attribute to your `AJAX` request. It's most likely throwing an error.

```
error: (err) => {
     console.warn(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the entire `$.ajax` block inside a `console.log($.ajax({...}));`.
Then look into the console for the response codes for more info
Also you can use this to find more about the case:

```
error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```